# How does a company get on the NASDAQ-100 index?

Tags: market-indexes, nasdaq

[Nasdaq 100 Index](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/nasdaq100.asp):

> The Nasdaq 100 Index is a basket of the 100 largest, most actively traded U.S companies listed on the Nasdaq stock exchange.

How is this calculated and decided on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASDAQ-100), the index consists of the 100 "largest" companies (by market capitalization) that meet certain requirements.

The requirements for being eligible for the index are:

> The NASDAQ has over the years put in place a series of stringent standards that companies must meet before being included in the index. Those standards include the following:
>
> - Being listed exclusively on NASDAQ in either the Global Select or Global Market tiers.
> - Being publicly offered on an established American market for three months.
> - Having average daily volume of 200,000 shares.
> - Being current in regards to quarterly and annual reports.
> - Not being in bankruptcy proceedings.

and the calculation of "size" is market cap (share price * number of shares outstanding), using the following values:

> There are two tools the NASDAQ uses to determine the market values of companies for the annual review:
>
> - Share Prices as of the last trading day in October.
> - Publicly announced share totals as of the last trading day of November.

Note that if a company falls out of the top 100, it does not necessarily get removed from the index immediately (see the  [Yearly rebalancing and re-ranking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASDAQ-100#Yearly_rebalancing_and_re-ranking) section)